# Why does journald use so much space to store so little data, and how can I reduce or compress the journal logs?

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald

I use journald with memory only logging limited to 55MB. But somehow this equates to less than a days worth of logging.

Config:

```
$ grep -v '^#' /etc/systemd/journald.conf

[Journal]
Storage=volatile
RuntimeMaxUse=50M
RuntimeKeepFree=75M
RuntimeMaxFileSize=5M
RuntimeMaxFiles=100
ForwardToSyslog=yes
MaxLevelSyslog=debug
```

Disk usage:

```
$ journalctl --disk-usage
Archived and active journals take up 55.0M in the file system.
```

The uncompressed size of the output of journalctl is 3.1M:

```
journalctl >logs; du -h logs
3.1M    logs
```

The compressed size is 153K:

```
$ journalctl |gzip >logs.gz; du -h logs.gz
153K    logs.gz
```

**UPDATE:**
Even when using journalctl -a -o verbose
The output data uses half of what journald consumes:

```
$ journalctl -a -o verbose >foo; df -h foo
27M     foo
```

And it compresses to a 50th of what journald consumes:

```
$ journalctl -a -o verbose |gzip >foo.z; du -h foo.z
1.7M    foo.z
```

**END UPDATE**

The journals are healthy according to journalctl --verify:

```
$ journalctl --verify
PASS: /run/log/journal/69357476ee55415c8407fc9f84dc235d/system.journal
PASS: /run/log/journal/69357476ee55415c8407fc9f84dc235d/system@93c2aae90b5b4ecaacf0d7339c8f33b2-000000000000e845-0005c8103bd20432.journal
PASS: /run/log/journal/69357476ee55415c8407fc9f84dc235d/system@93c2aae90b5b4ecaacf0d7339c8f33b2-000000000000db61-0005c80f5363b862.journal
PASS: /run/log/journal/69357476ee55415c8407fc9f84dc235d/system@93c2aae90b5b4ecaacf0d7339c8f33b2-000000000000ce71-0005c80e6a86dafe.journal
PASS: /run/log/journal/69357476ee55415c8407fc9f84dc235d/system@93c2aae90b5b4ecaacf0d7339c8f33b2-000000000000c18f-0005c80d81a2f3f8.journal
PASS: /run/log/journal/69357476ee55415c8407fc9f84dc235d/system@93c2aae90b5b4ecaacf0d7339c8f33b2-000000000000b4b6-0005c80c9979b637.journal
PASS: /run/log/journal/69357476ee55415c8407fc9f84dc235d/system@93c2aae90b5b4ecaacf0d7339c8f33b2-000000000000a7ca-0005c80bb0d1ff50.journal
PASS: /run/log/journal/69357476ee55415c8407fc9f84dc235d/system@93c2aae90b5b4ecaacf0d7339c8f33b2-0000000000009ade-0005c80ac8242caf.journal
PASS: /run/log/journal/69357476ee55415c8407fc9f84dc235d/system@93c2aae90b5b4ecaacf0d7339c8f33b2-0000000000008e05-0005c809dfaf56fb.journal
PASS: /run/log/journal/69357476ee55415c8407fc9f84dc235d/system@93c2aae90b5b4ecaacf0d7339c8f33b2-0000000000008118-0005c808f6e12c0d.journal
PASS: /run/log/journal/69357476ee55415c8407fc9f84dc235d/system@93c2aae90b5b4ecaacf0d7339c8f33b2-000000000000742e-0005c80806b00481.journal


$ ls -alh /run/log/journal/69357476ee55415c8407fc9f84dc235d/
total 55M
drwxr-s---+ 2 root systemd-journal  260 Jul 27 11:53 .
drwxr-sr-x  3 root systemd-journal   60 Jul 26 15:42 ..
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 5.0M Jul 27 02:08 system@93c2aae90b5b4ecaacf0d7339c8f33b2-000000000000742e-0005c80806b00481.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 5.0M Jul 27 03:13 system@93c2aae90b5b4ecaacf0d7339c8f33b2-0000000000008118-0005c808f6e12c0d.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 5.0M Jul 27 04:18 system@93c2aae90b5b4ecaacf0d7339c8f33b2-0000000000008e05-0005c809dfaf56fb.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 5.0M Jul 27 05:23 system@93c2aae90b5b4ecaacf0d7339c8f33b2-0000000000009ade-0005c80ac8242caf.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 5.0M Jul 27 06:28 system@93c2aae90b5b4ecaacf0d7339c8f33b2-000000000000a7ca-0005c80bb0d1ff50.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 5.0M Jul 27 07:33 system@93c2aae90b5b4ecaacf0d7339c8f33b2-000000000000b4b6-0005c80c9979b637.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 5.0M Jul 27 08:38 system@93c2aae90b5b4ecaacf0d7339c8f33b2-000000000000c18f-0005c80d81a2f3f8.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 5.0M Jul 27 09:43 system@93c2aae90b5b4ecaacf0d7339c8f33b2-000000000000ce71-0005c80e6a86dafe.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 5.0M Jul 27 10:48 system@93c2aae90b5b4ecaacf0d7339c8f33b2-000000000000db61-0005c80f5363b862.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 5.0M Jul 27 11:53 system@93c2aae90b5b4ecaacf0d7339c8f33b2-000000000000e845-0005c8103bd20432.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 5.0M Jul 27 12:18 system.journal
```

So why and how does journald use 359 times more space to store what compresses easily to 153K?

What's taking up 99.8% of the space, and is there a way to store more data at the cost of whatever that 99.8% is?

Comment: `journalctl >logs` ... did you check how far back the default output of `journalctl` goes?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in the question, but I didn't post the output so here it is: ``journalctl -n0``:
``-- Logs begin at Tue 2021-07-27 01:01:21 AEST, end at Tue 2021-07-27 12:40:31 AEST. --``

Comment: What about `journalctl -a -o verbose -n all`?

Comment: `-n all` doesn't affect it

Comment: Poettering describes the journal file internals [here](https://systemd.io/JOURNAL_FILE_FORMAT/). `journalctl --header` on my logs usually shows *Data Hash Table Fill: 75%* which is the reason they get rotated. Presumably a lot of space is preallocated as even empty journals take up the same space (and are not sparse).